# How to determine the fixed and random effect using linear mixed effect model?

Tags: r, lme4

I would like to investigate the variation of eye size among species and among type using linear mixed model.
However, I am a little bit confuse to determine whether to be random effect and fixed effect. I tried to use this model: `lmer(Eyesize ~ Species + (1|Type)`

this is the data : [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-cMmc2IaBSkO2LkuEEHOtAShZ-d5oXrn/view)

this is my code:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(multcomp)

example_data <-read.csv("EXAMPLE 1.csv", h= TRUE)
head(example_data)
result = lmer(Eyesize ~ Species + (1|Type), data=example_data)
summary(result)
```

I got the result of an analysis like this

[image: result]

I cannot get the analysis result for species A. I think it is because I used the wrong random or fixed effect in this mode. I also want to indicate the variation with the letter using Tukey analysis. Could anyone help me to solve this?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd level of Species doesnt show up because it's made into the reference level.

It sounds like you are after a post-hoc comparison, which can be done on the lme4 object using `emmeans::emmeans`.

In the future, please make the data easier to access, like this:

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
# df <- read.csv("stack_q_lme4.csv")
# df$Eyesize <- as.numeric(df$Eyesize)
# df$factor <- as.factor(df$Species)
# df$Type <- as.factor(df$Type)
#dput(df)
df <- structure(list(Eyesize = c(0.428278862, 0.400995265, 0.39874335, 
                           0.393709024, 0.425950648, 0.422276073, 0.423718381, 0.436375912, 
                           0.434729533, 0.44292607, 0.474962122, 0.480422148, 0.446239189, 
                           0.456237883, 0.479825541, 0.319118225, 0.34803004, 0.392926567, 
                           0.355179776, 0.327142563, 0.292814474, 0.295765514, 0.268828342, 
                           0.269960081, 0.2834768, 0.356604986, 0.348001735, 0.360895441, 
                           0.342982001, 0.366047801, 0.317237392, 0.293341926, 0.308761142, 
                           0.30039708, 0.308900879, 0.326311003, 0.33954796, 0.316756444, 
                           0.317607287, 0.33562927), Species = c("Species A", "Species A", 
                                                                 "Species A", "Species A", "Species A", "Species A", "Species A", 
                                                                 "Species A", "Species A", "Species A", "Species A", "Species A", 
                                                                 "Species A", "Species A", "Species A", "Species B", "Species B", 
                                                                 "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", 
                                                                 "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", 
                                                                 "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", 
                                                                 "Species B", "Species B", "Species B", "Species C", "Species C", 
                                                                 "Species C", "Species C", "Species C"), Type = structure(c(6L, 
                                                                                                                            6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                            5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                            1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Type B", "Type K", "Type L", 
                                                                                                                                                                    "Type P", "Type Q", "type R", "Type T", "Type W"), class = "factor"), 
               factor = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                    3L), .Label = c("Species A", "Species B", "Species C"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                              -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is what *I think* you're after, marginal means and pairwise comparisons of species.

```
m1 <- lmer(Eyesize ~ Species + (1|Type), data=df)

emmeans(m1, pairwise ~ Species)
# $emmeans
# Species   emmean     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# Species A  0.436 0.0189  5    0.388    0.485
# Species B  0.323 0.0163  5    0.281    0.365
# Species C  0.327 0.0327  5    0.243    0.411
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 
# 
# $contrasts
# contrast              estimate     SE df t.ratio p.value
# Species A - Species B  0.11354 0.0250  5   4.547  0.0140
# Species A - Species C  0.10919 0.0377  5   2.893  0.0742
# Species B - Species C -0.00435 0.0365  5  -0.119  0.9922
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
# P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would like to ask, is it correct to determine species as the fixed effect and type as the random effect? in this formula "Eyesize ~ Species + (1|Type), data=df". I also want to investigate the differentiation among types. Could I use emmeans?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct to model type as a random effect, that's more of a scientific question, and I don't know enough about species eye size. You can look at the modes of the random effects with lme4, using lme4::ranef. If you want a significance test of the differences it's harder with random effects - maybe ad hoc sampling or full bayes will get you what you need. However, fixed effects would certainly be simple.